# Access 2016 Alternate Row Color

Tags: vba, ms-access, formatting

I am trying to alternate my row color on a report that utilizes grouping. The issue is when moving from one group to the next, the color always starts as white. This can lead to awkward chunks of white rows with no alternate color rows.

If my grouping goes 1,1,1,2,3,3,4 my row colors will become white, color, white, white, white, color, white which is very unappealing visually.

I have tried using VBA during the `On Format` event. However, the code I have tried has the same results.

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)

Dim Color   As Boolean

    If Color Then
        Me.Section(0).AlternateBackColor = vbWhite
    Else
        Me.Section(0).AlternateBackColor = RGB(197, 217, 242)
    End If
    
    Color = Not (Color)

    
End Sub
```

What is a method that will ignore/bypass the groups to keep the alternating colors consistent?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could pass to the following group whether the group has an even or and odd count of  rows. Something like:

```vb
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)

    Static OddEven As Boolean

    If OddEven Then
        Me.Section(0).AlternateBackColor = vbWhite
        Me.Section(0).BackColor = RGB(197, 217, 242)
    Else
        Me.Section(0).BackColor = vbWhite
        Me.Section(0).AlternateBackColor = RGB(197, 217, 242)
    End If
    
    ' Get RowCount somehow.
    OddEven = RowCount Mod 2
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Would doing a record count work for the last bit? Or is there a simple function I could use in a group header (set to not be visible) that can count the rows and give me that number?

Comment: Somehow, yes. Or a running sum in the report of a field having value 1.